# What is difference between a server and PC

Tags: networking

This thing confuses me a lot that what makes a server different from my laptop . Will my laptop serves same like a server . if i installed a server operating system like windows SE or red hat EL In it ?

Comment: Sorry, but this is a basic computer terminology question, so is off topic here. That said, the answer is basically that "server" is relative. If you use a machine as a server (e.g. a webserver or database server) then it is a server. You can also buy server machines which basically come with more powerful hardware (usually several dozen CPUs, loads of RAM etc). So "server" can describe what the machine does, or it can describe what the machine is designed for.

Comment: To make it simple: a server computer *serves* other computers (typically provides data via a local network or via the internet). But as pointed out by @terdon, the term 'server' can be used for the hardware too, and also for the special software or dedicated operating system used in a server computer.

Comment: In general a server runs without a desktop interface and uns servers or daemons such as a mail server, FTP, http, etc. In general a laptop runs a graphical interface or desktop and does not run services but rather serves as a client, ie you run a mail app or firefox. Dedicated servers tend to have different hardware such as RAID , lower quality graphics cards, multiple network cards, and lack sound cards. The line blurs a bit as you can run server software from a laptop, but in general "server" means dedicated to services rather than a desktop.